# npm install fails due private packages not found although the token is set in the .npmrc file

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

Environment details are like below:

- Ubuntu **20.04**
- Node **v10.22.1**
- npm **6.14.6**

I have a frontend project(react) where I need to create CI/CD pipeline. I failing to set it up locally due to private packages not being found during `npm install`.

The error is like below:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@org/package-name/-/package-name-0.1.24.tgz
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@org/package-name@^0.1.24' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'project-name'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rando/.npm/_logs/2021-09-23T07_52_46_228Z-debug.log
```

First, I have verified if I have access to this package by authenticating with my account in npmjs.com. Below you can see that I am part of the organization and have access to all packages of that organization.

[image]

I have configured the `.npmrc` file located in /home/user like below:

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/
//registry.npmjs.com/:_authToken=${authToken}
```

I have generated multiple authentication tokens from my `npmjs.com` account and tried running npm install after placing the newly generated token on the `.npmrc` file.

Also, I tried to install the library in isolation like below:

```
npm i @org/package-name
```

But still failed with the same error 404.

I tried to log in the terminal like below:

```
npm login
Username:
Password:
Email: (this IS public) {may email}
Logged in as {my username} on https://registry.npmjs.com/.

npm i @org/package-name
```

And it still failed with the same error. I will appreciate any help toward solving this issue.

Regards,
Rando.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to fix this issue by modifying the `.npmrc` file like below:

```
//registry.npmjs.com/:_authToken=${authToken}
```

Removing the `registry=https://registry.npmjs.com/` fixed the issue. I don't quite understand why specifying the registry cause this trouble.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a .npmrc file in your home directory with the correct token, but an empty/incorrect .npmrc file in the project directory you're trying to run `npm install` from, you may be getting a 404 because the file in the current directory overrides your global setting.

I was getting a 404 on a private repo, though I confirmed my token was correct:

```
$ npm install @myorg/a-private-repo
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@myorg%2fa-private-repo - Not found

# huh? My token is correct...
$ cat ~/.npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=npm_CORRECT_TOKEN
```

Eventually I noticed a .npmrc file in the project directory that CI/CD uses:

```
$ cat .npmrc
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=${CICD_TOKEN}
```

This `CICD_TOKEN` variable isn't set in my local environment, hence the failure.

To fix it, I temporarily moved the local .npmrc file, at which point the install succeeded:

```
$ mv .npmrc .npmrc.bak


$ npm install @myorg/a-private-repo

added 1 package, and audited ...
```

This burned a lot of time, so I hope this helps someone who might find themselves in the same situation.

Comment: Thank you! This was my issue as well. I was just about to start pulling my hair out...

Answer (score -1):

I found this hapens with node versions below 13.
Ive been able to fix same issue after changed all address referencing https://registry.npmjs.com to https://registry.npmjs.org

```
registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
@some_org:registry=https://registry.npmjs.org
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=some_token
```