# npm install failing with 404 error (/@fortawesome%2fpro-regular-svg-icons - Not found) althoug token is set

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, npm

After fixing the failure from the private package not found in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69296524/npm-install-fails-due-private-packages-not-found-although-the-token-is-set-in-th).

I am stuck at the error ```font awesome`` library not found. Below is the error message details:

```
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/@fortawesome%2fpro-regular-svg-icons - Not found
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404  '@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons@^5.15.2' is not in the npm registry.
npm ERR! 404 You should bug the author to publish it (or use the name yourself!)
npm ERR! 404 It was specified as a dependency of 'data-qa-frontend'
npm ERR! 404 
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/rando/.npm/_logs/2021-09-23T12_59_34_988Z-debug.log
```

If I add the auth_token for font awesome registry like below:

```
//registry.npmjs.com/:_authToken={TOKEN}
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken={TOKEN}
```

It fails due to a private package not being found. While removing the font-awesome registry it throws the error of font-awesome library not found.

Below is a part package.json file:

```
{
  "name": "project-name",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@org/private-package": "^0.1.24",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-pro": "^5.15.3",
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/pro-duotone-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-light-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/pro-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
```

Thank you in advance. I will appreciate any help in solving this issue.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After many trials,

I fixed this issue by following the step below:

1. Modify the `.npmrc` file to have the content below:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken={TOKEN}
```

2. Go to the terminal and login to npm like below:

```
npm login
Username:
Password:
Email: (this IS public) {may email}
Logged in as {my username} on https://registry.npmjs.com/.
```

After this check the `.npmrc file`, it should look like below:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken={TOKEN}
//registry.npmjs.org/:_authToken=npm_{TOKEN}
```

3. Finally run npm install at the root of your project and will complete it successfully.

Comment: I don't have a .npmrc file.

Comment: It should be in your user's home directory by default.  Tweak the configuration to show hidden files.

Answer (score 5):

According to the official documentation found [here](https://fontawesome.com/docs/web/setup/packages):

**1) You could set Up npm Token for All Projects:**
This global setup will allow any of your projects to use the Font Awesome package and your token. For the global set up, run:

```
npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/
npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```

**2) You could set Up npm Token for a Specific Project:**
This per-project setup lets you configure each project individually, which can be good for teams and CI/CD.

You'll need to create a `.npmrc` file in the root of your project (or wherever your `package.json` file lives) and put this in it:

```
@fortawesome:registry=https://npm.fontawesome.com/
//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX
```